# Tag specific images on page as Creative Commons?

Tags: html

I have an image archive site with multiple photos of mine per page. Most of them, but not all, use [a Creative Commons license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/). Can I add machine-readable html (e.g. something like a rel attribute) to define those <img>'s as holding that specific license? My overall goal is for those images to then be found in e.g. a  `site:example.com` Google Image Search where the user uses the "Creative Commons licenses" search tools setting. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the title tag instead and make sure to fill in the alt tag too. There is no way to force Google to index anything on your site. But, Google does look at the title and alt tag when indexing. The alt tag gives higher ranking points per se. I'm not sure if Google index's the alt tag as much as Google wants to see that there is an alt tag that corresponds to the image. But the title tag Google does at least on my site has indexed. That way when you do a search at `site:domain.tld "Creative Commons"` the images that have Creative Commons in the title...IF...they have been indexed by Google should show up. I suggest keeping a common naming convention for your images. Ex. title="Creative Commons: Rocky Mountains" | title="Creative Commons: Mount Rushmore" etc. Hope that helps.